# How to cross compile a library in Ubuntu for mingw/msys2 in Windows?

Tags: cross-compiling, configure, msys2

I have a sqlite library which I need to use in msys2 environment, it doesn't have access to internet. I want to compile and give the path to binaries in the msys2 environment.

How do I do the regular

```sh
./configure --prefix=/path/to/my/folder/
make 
make install
```

`with x64_86-w64-mingw-gcc` as the default compiler and it's respective libraries.

---

I tried with `export CC=x64_86-w64-mingw-gcc` first and running the above commands. 
It gives me an error at

`checking whether we are cross compiling: error...`
`If you are cross compiling, use --host`.

How do I use host? What are the values, I should pass to configure, so that the library is a binary usable in Msys2 environment.

Comment: MSYS2 has a MINGW 64-bit sqlite package already.  You can install it with `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3`.  Or if you really wan't connect to the internet, you should be able to download the packages you need from http://repo.msys2.org/ and install them with `pacman -U filename`.  Why do you need to compile this yourself and why do you need to do it from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say about all different architectures but for mingw platform, we can

`./configure --prefix=/path/to/my/folder --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32`

You need not specify CC. It'll use the above host as the prefix for your compiler, i.e., will use `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`.

---

I don't know if it is true, but you can try on your own, if your compiler is `arm64-gcc` then try to put `--host=arm64`

---

This solved my problem, I don't claim this to be generic solution, until someone answers a more generic one, I'll mark my answer as the correct one.